# Char * sharing same memory

Tags: c, gcc

Here is my code and I need a clarification in the output of this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void )
{
char name1[10] = "Rajan" , name2[10] = "Rajan" ;
char *name3 = "Chennai" , *name4 = "Chennai" ;
printf("\nAddress for name1 and name2 : %p and %p",name1,name2) ;
printf("\nAddress for name3 and name4 : %p and %p",name3,name4) ;
return 0 ;
}
```

The ouput of this code is

```
Address for name1 and name2 : 0x7fff9e6cbe10 and 0x7fff9e6cbe20
Address for name3 and name4 : 0x400760 and 0x400760
```

Here the address of the values `name1` and `name2` are different since i allocated two different arrays. But in the case of `name3` and `name4`, the address is same, why is it not different? It won't create a different memory and allocate name for the value `Chennai`? Why is it pointing to the same memory?

Comment: Note that you won't be able to modify what `name3` or `name4` points to and so it doesn't really matter if they are the same thing.

Comment: If you would attempt to print the address of the string literals used for name1 and name2, you'd get the same behavior: `printf("\nAddress for name1 and name2 : %p and %p","Rajan","Rajan") ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

name3 and name4 are string literals , will be stored in read only memory and you cant modify each char in string literal. you are trying to store same characters in both the pointer so to optimize memory allocation your string "chennai" will get memory only once in the read only address and name3 and name4 will point to same address. you can change each and every character in name1 and name2 so it is giving different address for both

Answer (score 5):

The standard allows it:

> 6.4.5 - 7
>
> **It  is  unspeciﬁed  whether  these  arrays  are  distinct**  provided 
>   their  elements  have  the appropriate  values.  If the  program 
>   attempts  to  modify  such  an  array, the  behavior  is undeﬁned.

I mean, it shouldn't matter as long as you don't modify them, right ?

Answer (score 0):

because they are char* to const memory.   You can't change the string pointed to by name3 or name4,  but you can change the strings pointed to by name1 and name2 because name1 and name2 are allocating memory and then getting the name "Rajan" initialized into that memory.

you could make name3 or name4 point to the something else.  But at the moment, you've said to point it to a const string  ( and its not going to duplicate those const strings....  you'll also find it stores another const string to "Rajan" that it uses to initialize name1 and name2

Answer (score 0):

"Chennai" is a const， name3 and name4 point a same place.

Answer (score 0):

When your program is compiled, the compiler forms the object code file, which contains your machine code and a table of all the string constants declared in the program.

the statement 
`char *name3= "Chennai";`

causes name3 to point to the address of the string "Chennai" in the string constant table. same applies to name4. so both name3 and name4 points to same address.

Since this string is in the string constant table, and therefore technically a part of the executable code, you cannot modify it. You can only point to it and use it in a read-only manner.

http://euklid.mi.uni-koeln.de/c/mirror/mickey.lcsc.edu/%257Esteve/c13.html gives more idea on how string is handled in C.

Comment: String constants are not technically part of the executable code. On typical platforms, they are both marked not writeable but are in separate sections, and only code sections are marked executable.

Answer (score 0):

String literals were always intended to be unmodifiable. Since they are unmodifiable, there is no harm in allowing them to share space, since one string literal object could not be altered by modifying another.

However, the `const` attribute did not exist in C originally, so the language had to allow pointers to string literals to be assigned to plain (non-const) pointers. To retain compatibility with old code, the C standard still permits string literals to be assigned to non-const pointers. But you must not try to modify them.

If C were recreated anew, string literals would likely produce pointers with the `const` attribute.

(String literals used to initialize arrays are special; there, a string literal is essentially just a compile-time specification of what to put into the array. They do not have addresses that you can assign to pointers.)